# Iterate over arguments in a bash script and make use of their numbers

Tags: bash, loops, command-line

If I want to iterate over all arguments it is as easy as `for i in "$@"; do ...`. However, let's say I want to start with the second argument and also make use of the arguments' positions for some basic calculation.

As an example I want to shorten these commands into one loop:

```
grep -v 'foobar' "$2" | grep -f $file > output1.txt
grep -v 'foobar' "$3" | grep -f $file > output2.txt
grep -v 'foobar' "$4" | grep -f $file > output3.txt
grep -v 'foobar' "$5" | grep -f $file > output4.txt
```

I tried many variations like `for i in {2..5}; do grep -v 'foobar' "$$i" | grep -f $file > output$(($i-1)).txt; done`; however, it seems bash expansion doesn't work like this.

EDIT:

Seems I made a mistake not emphasizing that I need to make use of the argument's position/number (i.e., 2 from `$2`). It's important because the output files get used separately later in the script. All of the provided answers so far seem correct but I don't know how to use them to make use of the argument's "number".

Comment: Pretty sure [andlrc's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37054146/3266847) lets you use the parameter *and* its index, doesn't that work for you?

Comment: *How* do you get the indices? Are they in an array?

Comment: @BenjaminW. I made a mistake in the syntax before but yes, you are right, it does work now. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you do *not* want to shift off the first unneeded arguments you can use the [indirection expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#indirection):

```
for i in {2..5}; do
  echo "${!i}"
done
```

Comment: Thank you. This lets me use the argument's index easily and that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 14):

Couple correct answers already, another way could be:

```
for (( i=2; i <= "$#"; i++ )); do
    echo "arg position: ${i}"
    echo "arg value: ${!i}"
done
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also make use of array indexes directly:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in "${@:2}"; do
    echo "$i"
done
```

Which will iterate over the arguments beginning with the second argument. It will also preserve whitespace in arguments when quoted. e.g.

```
$ bash args.sh one two "three four" five
two
three four
five
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use `shift` to move positional parameter once (thus discarding `$1`):

```
fn() { arg1="$1"; shift; for arg; do echo "$arg"; done; }
```

Call it as:

```
fn val1 val2 val3 val4
```

**Output:**

```
val2
val3
val4
```

Answer (score 0):

Above answers are correct. Another approach:

```
a=("${@:2}")

for i in ${!a[@]}; do
    echo "$i = ${a[i]}"
done
```

Comment: There is no need for the `a` array, simple `for i in "${@:2}"; do ...` is sufficient.

Comment: Agreed... rather, that's what I assigned to `a`. OP wanted index - `i` too. I would say, JStill's answer covers both the requirements in the much optimum way.

Answer (score 0):

`$@` is similar to an array, with the small difference that it is one-based and not zero-based (`$0` is the name of the shell or shell script), and it can't be indexed (`${@[1]}` won't work to access `$1`). You can use [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) (more specifically: substring expansion) to access a subset of your positional parameters:

```
$ set arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 arg5   # Set $1, $2, $3, $4, $5
$ for i in "${@:2}"; do echo "$i"; done
arg2
arg3
arg4
arg5
```

Notice that this will not actually allow you to use the index of the argument *and* the argument itself. To do that, you'd have to either turn the positional parameters into a regular array and deal with the index offset by one (`$1` would have index 0), or use indirect expansion (see [andlrc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37054146/3266847)).

Example of the first method:

```
$ set arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 arg5
$ args=("$@")
$ for i in 3 2 5 1 4; do echo "\$$i is ${args[$((i-1))]}"; done
$3 is arg3
$2 is arg2
$5 is arg5
$1 is arg1
$4 is arg4
```

Clearly, `${args[$((i-1))]}` is rather messy, but it works.

---

Side note: if you want to access *all* positional parameters, you can use a convenient shorthand:

```
$ for i; do echo "$i"; done
arg1
arg2
arg3
arg4
arg5
```

`for` without the `in` part loops over all positional parameters (see [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Looping-Constructs)).