# Programatically cycle through arguments given to a script or function

Tags: bash, arguments, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to cycle through an unknown number of arguments given to a bash script (or function within), to effectively handle the odds (`$1`, `$3`, etc.) and evens (`$2`, `$4`, etc.) in different ways.

I know I can get the number of arguments using `$#`, and the arguments themselves using `$@`, and of course `echo $1 $2` or `printf '%s\n' "$1"` both work.   What I'm needing to do is effectively echo the odds `echo $1 $3 $5 ...` with an unknown number, then separately deal with the evens, and count the characters of these individually also, so need to get these programmatically if at all possible.

**Note:** Some of the input will have spaces, but where will always have quotes.  An example would be `1 "This one" "Another one" "and another" "last one"`.

I've tried (these are just to get output for brevity):

Putting `$@` into an array of itself, in both for and while arrangements (understanding this zero indexes the array):

```sh
indexedarray="$@"
for i in {0..$#..2}; do #This in itself creates an error ({0..5..2}: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "{0..5..2}")).
  echo -n "${indexedarray[$i]}
done
```

This produces empty output:

```sh
i=0
while [ $i -lt $# ]; do
    echo ${INDEXEDARRAY[i]}
    ((i+2))
done
```

And the (somewhat) obvious foibles inside of for or while loops:

```sh
  echo "${$@[$i]}"
  echo $"${i}"
```

None of which work.

Any ideas on how I might improve this, and get the output I need?

Comment: `indexedarray="$@"` does not define an array but a string. Try `indexedarray=("$@")` instead.

Comment: `{0..$#}` does not work because braces are expanded before variables, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19432753/6770384). For examples on how to access command line argument without `$1`, `$2`, … see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/255898/6770384) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37053780/6770384).

Comment: @Socowi - that was it, sort of.  I'd tried `($@)` in the for loop, but neglected to in the while loop.  Though curiously `(((i++))` works, but `((i+2))` goes into an infinite loop, and only displays `$1`.  I'll have a look and see if I can modify any of the others from the other questions, though.  Thanks for that!

Comment: `((i+2))` computes a result and discards it. You probably wanted to write `((i+=2))`. Without the assignment `i` keeps its initial value, hence the endless loop.

Comment: Yes, that's right!  My c-style arithmetic is slowly coming back to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you want to print every other argument. Here are some ways to do it.

My favorite (despite being a bit hacky):

```
printf '%s\n%.0s' "$@"
```

The next logical approach

```
while (($# > 0)); do
  echo "$1"
  shift
  shift
  # `shift 2` won't shift if there is only one argument left
done
```

And the most general approach

```
a=("$@")
for ((i=0; i<$#; i+=2)); do
  echo "${a[i]}"
done
```

Comment: So I discovered from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37054146/7831034), there's also the `${!i}` designation, which suits my needs perfectly, without having to define a seperate array.

Comment: `while x=$1 && shift; do echo "$x"; shift; done` would work as well. The `shift` in the condition doubles as the way to move past the current argument as well as the test for if `x` was assigned a value at all. The `shift` in the body continues to skip an argument.

Comment: `for _; do echo "$1"; shift; shift; done` work as well.